# Partial Least Squares NIPALS Algorithm when Y has more than one column (PLS2)

Tags: partial-least-squares

I wanted to exactly understand how Partial Least Squares Regression works and thus got my hands onto a paper called "A Simple Explanation of Partial Least Squares". 
After some thinking and consulting on other related papers and tutorials I think I found something strange in what is presented to be the PLS-NIPALS algorithm here [Link to paper](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~kee/pls.pdf).

[image: Algorithm description from the paper]

From my understanding what is denoted as **P** here are the weights that are usually denoted as **W**. 
But then, X is deflated with what appears to be the weights when it should be deflated using the loadings. (I've never see the loadings corresponding to X be calculated anywhere in this presentation of the algorithm)

Is this normal? Is it a mistake from the creator?